# Represent map of json and null in a record field

Tags: json, ballerina

I need to define a record that can be used to represent the following values.

```
{
    "ID": "101",
    "name": "Dog",
    "types": null
}
```

```
{
    "ID": "101",
    "name": "Dog",
    "types": {
        "color": "black"
    }
}
```

The `types` field can be either JSON or null.
The equivalent type is

```
type Animal record {
    string ID;
    string name;
    map<json> types?;
};
```

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If the value of the `types` field can be null, that requires the `types` record field to allow nil/null and that can be represented by `map<json>?`.
An optional field `map<json> types?;` means the `types` field may or may not be present, but if present it will be a `map<json>` value. To allow nil/null the type has to allow nil.

E.g.,

- `map<json>? types;` - if the field is always present and the value
  can be map or nil
- `map<json>? types?;` - if the field may or may not be present, and
  when present can be map or nil